# npm install ->Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script

Tags: angular, reactjs, npm, ionic3, node-sass

I'm trying to do `npm install` and an error appears :

```
Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script.
```

I tried to delete `node_modules` and then reinstall it, same error appears.
what will be the solution?

node v8.9.3
npm v5.4.2
ionic 3.19.0

Comment: Please post full log of the error.

Answer (score 169):

Got the same problem (node v10.3.0, ionic 3.13.0). This worked :

- Delete `package-`**lock**`.json`,
- Delete `node_modules` folder,
- Run `npm install` again.

Comment: It worked. Anyone who is having this issue should try this and I am also wondering that cleaning the cache without removing the whole folder should also work.

Comment: Is package.backup.json a replacement for package-lock.json? I can't find package-lock.json in my ionic app folder

Answer (score 59):

try

```
sudo rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules
sudo npm cache clean --force
npm i --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Comment: Ran this without `sudo` worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: Do not use sudo with npm i

Answer (score 44):

**Just Try with this command hope it will very helpful.**
it's working for me

```
sudo npm install -g node-sass@4.5.0 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: Hours, spent looking into this nightmare and this is the resolution on my mac.  Thank you!

Comment: `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root` works as well.

Comment: That works for me after using `sudo npm cache clean --force`

Comment: @Abhay:- tell me one thing bro above command is affect another ionic project or not?

Comment: @Kapilsoni its not affected on my project.

Comment: @AbhaySingh above error is resolved but got another erros

Comment: This solution still works in 2020! Saved my life. Thanks!

Comment: @SirPedr Most importantly that issue is still there in 2020...I keep coming back here every few years.

Answer (score 26):

rolling back to node `v10.17.0` fixed the problem to me.

You can use nvm to do so:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

```
> nvm install 10.17.0
> nvm use 10.17.0
> node -v
10.17.0
```

Comment: this works flawlessly! saved the day man!

Comment: You are my hero))I searched a correct version for nvm, you save my time.

Answer (score 21):

I also had to face the same problem with `node v12.16.3`.

1. Remove `node-sass` dependency from your `package.json` if it is mentioned in your `dependencies`.This will allow npm to install other required dependencies without any disruption.
2. Delete `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder from your project.
3. Force clean the entire NPM cache by using following comand.

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
4. Re-Install all the dependencies.

   ```
   npm install
   ```
5. Now you can install `node-sass`.

   ```
   npm i node-sass
   ```

Comment: If you'll don't want to downgrade your node version, you can try this solution, it worked for me! Thanks @Aravinda

Comment: Node makes me say things like "I can't believe this worked"...

Answer (score 18):

Node-sass@4.5.0 cannot be installed on node 8

[image]

Please update  either node-sass or node version compatible

Go to https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases to check which fits for you

Answer (score 6):

use this flag `--unsafe-perm=true`

```
sudo npm i gulp-sass -ES --unsafe-perm=true
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Uninstall current **npm** and install lower versions, it is a common error if version didn't match, downgrading node/npm will mostly fix this kind of issues

```
npm install -g npm@4.6.1
```

Comment: i did npm uninstall >> then npm install -g npm@4.6.1,
not working

Comment: I used nvm to install `lts/boron` which is the latest node 6. after that everything ran fine

Answer (score 3):

After uninstalling node-sass try cleaning your npm cache. After that try installing node-sass again.

```
npm cache clean && npm install node-sass
```

Comment: i tried it with npm@4.6.1, should i upgrade it to v8.9.3 as it was

Comment: dumping the cache worked for me, but for my npm version it had to be `npm cache clean --force && npm install node-sass`

Answer (score 3):

The minimum version of node-sass that supports Node 8 is 4.5.3. You'll need to upgrade your node-sass or downgrade your Node version. Ionic may also have separate issues since it isn't a tested platform with node-sass.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to **[install SASS](http://sass-lang.com/install)**.

I remember havign this issue in AngularJS with compass, I had to install it with Ruby to make it work. This was 3 years ago, so I'm not sure this would be the solution, but it doesn't cost anything except time to try, right ?

Comment: pm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jsleiman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-17T10_13_04_021Z-debug.log

Comment: Ok I give up. Good luck.

Comment: Installing sass globally worked for me. I still see the npm build errors but they seem to be ignored and npm install succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to take the following steps to "resolve" this problem:

1. Create folder at the root: `mkdir ~/safe_node_module`;
2. Download package `wget -q https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node` and then send to the folder created in step 1;
3. Set the export environment variable `export SASS_BINARY_PATH=/home/ronaldaraujo/safe_node_module/linux-x64-72_binding.node`;
4. Install packages normally `npm i`;

Answer (score 2):

Install the higher version of node-sass

```
npm install node-sass@4.13.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a new install with Keystone.js. I was able to get pass this issue by removing Node Sass from package.json and running npm install again. Being that the package wasn't listed under node modules. And it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by force installing node-sass locally: npm install -f node-sass

I was pretty sure I knew what I was doing... [this](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1980)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do `npm install` in the ionic project and an error appears

> Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.

The following steps worked for me ionic project

Remove `npm` than run the following commands

> npm i
>
> npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest--unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Answer (score 0):

Sometime unable to download file win32-x64-79_binding.node due to your proxy restrict  to download so plase follow this below link set them manually.
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2773

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on **Windows** running Node.js version **v14.17.3**

```
npm install -g node-sass@4.5.0 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root --force
```

**Note:** My node-sass version was **node-sass@4.13.1**. But the above command will work for other versions too. Just replace the node-sass version number in the above command with your required node-sass version.

Answer (score -1):

The following steps worked for me

```
npm install -g node-sass@4.5.0 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

npm cache clean


npm install
```