# ERROR npm install - node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Whenever I npm install, I get an

````
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.```

I've tried deleting node_modules, but I am getting not luck.
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install ->Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298361/npm-install-failed-at-the-node-sass4-5-0-postinstall-script)

Comment: I have numerous package-lock.json in my node_modules. Shouldn't just deleting node_modules do the trick? That said I do have a package.json outside my node_modules. What if I delete that?

Comment: I think the recommendation is to blow away `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` in your _current_ directory. Otherwise when you install again, it will install the same broken thing. It's the "reboot" for an npm install.

Comment: Are you running it within docker? Because I had the same error with docker windows. I switched to linux and everything worked fine.

Comment: SOLVED: Downloaded the wrong version of nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

You have to upgrade your [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) 4.13.1 to node-sass@4.14
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Install earlier version of Node. Version 12.16 should work.